# <br> comes up for no reason on specific page

Tags: php, html

can anybody help and tell me where does it come from? there's not 
 in the code, but it comes up and breaks all of my design. on other pages everything works correctly, just here.

index: http://pastebin.com/GMaMKCnH
thats what i include: http://pastebin.com/vH9e6sby

**Here's the inspect element:**

[image]

Comment: <br> is wrong, try to use <br/>

Comment: check after the tr td tag

Comment: post the code also, instead of image

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: tr must be inside a table. Also, always post code as text, never as image

Comment: It comes from your php code which we don't see.

Comment: Added links to pastebin.

Comment: @UdhayTitus Not true. `<br>` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yon need to add opening tag `<table>` after `<body>`

Comment: I had it, added whole code now: http://pastebin.com/GMaMKCnH

Comment: Why you put `<table>` and `<td>` inside `<head>`. It should be after `<body>`

Comment: I changed that, but this <br> still comes up from nowhere.

Comment: Please show your code after changes